# Polygon transactions are stuck/transaction underpriced error - ethersjs

Tags: javascript, transactions, blockchain, polygon, ethers.js

Since June 14, 2023, no more transactions are recorded on the Polygon blockchain.

The bug is related to the calculation of transaction fees, the calculation method that worked is as follows:

```
    parse(data: any): any {
      return ethers.utils.parseUnits(Math.ceil(data) + '', 'gwei');
    }

  async calcGas(gasEstimated: any): Promise<any> {
    const gas = {
      gasLimit: gasEstimated, //.mul(110).div(100)
      maxFeePerGas: ethers.BigNumber.from(40000000000),
      maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.BigNumber.from(40000000000),
    };

    try {
      const { data } = await this. httpService
        .get(
          this.isMainnet()
            ? 'https://gasstation-mainnet.matic.network/v2'
            : 'https://gasstation-mumbai.matic.today/v2',
        )
        .toPromise();

      gas.maxFeePerGas = this.parse(data.fast.maxFee);
      gas.maxPriorityFeePerGas = this.parse(data.fast.maxPriorityFee);
    } catch (error) {}
    return gas;
  }
```

But the endpoints:

- mainnet: https://gasstation-mainnet.matic.network/v2
- testnet: https://gasstation-mumbai.matic.today/v2
  no longer return data.

see information link: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2828

In order to solve the bug, a new calculation method has beed implemented but does not work on mainnet, here is the new method:

```
  async calcGas(gasEstimated: any): Promise<any> {
    const feeData = await this.provider?.getFeeData();

    // INFO: add 10% to estimated gas
    const gasEstimatedUpdated = gasEstimated?.mul(110).div(100);
    const feeDataWithGasLimit = {
      ...feeData,
      gasLimit: gasEstimatedUpdated,
    };

    delete feeDataWithGasLimit?.gasPrice;
    return feeDataWithGasLimit;
  }
```

on mainnet on transaction an error 'transaction underpriced' is returned:

```
Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":96,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"transaction underpriced\"}}", error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\":
```

Finally with an other method using https://owlracle.info/docs did not returned error but the transaction is not registered on blockchain (cf explorer).

here is the code :

```
    parse(data: any): any {
      return ethers.utils.parseUnits(Math.ceil(data) + '', 'gwei');
    }
  
    async calcGas(gasEstimated: any): Promise<any> {
      const feeData = await this.provider?.getFeeData();  
      const gasEstimatedUpdated = gasEstimated?.mul(150).div(100);
      const feeDataWithGasLimit = {
        ...feeData,
        gasLimit: gasEstimatedUpdated,
      };
  
      delete feeDataWithGasLimit?.gasPrice;      
      const gas = feeDataWithGasLimit;
      
      if (this.isMainnet()) {
        // INFO: get fee from remote service
        try {
          const apiKey = 'TO_DEFINE';
          const { data } = await this.httpService
            .get(`https://api.owlracle.info/v4/poly/gas?apikey=${apiKey}`)
            .toPromise();
          const speeds = data?.speeds;
          const fastestSpeed = speeds?.reduce(function (prev, current) {
            return prev?.acceptance > current?.acceptance ? prev : current;
          });
          const computedMaxFeePerGas = this.parse(fastestSpeed.maxFeePerGas);
          gas.maxFeePerGas = computedMaxFeePerGas;
          const computedMaxPriorityFeePerGas = this.parse(
            fastestSpeed.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
          );
          gas.maxPriorityFeePerGas = computedMaxPriorityFeePerGas;
          // INFO: response sample :
          // {
          //     "timestamp": "2023-06-30T07:18:42.231Z",
          //     "lastBlock": 44507478,
          //     "avgTime": 2.170854271356784,
          //     "avgTx": 68.615,
          //     "avgGas": 238605.93573515464,
          //     "speeds": [
          //         {
          //             "acceptance": 0.35,
          //             "maxFeePerGas": 170.352683911,
          //             "maxPriorityFeePerGas": 38.75987124300002,
          //             "baseFee": 131.592812668,
          //             "estimatedFee": 0.026399924954836184
          //         },
          //         {
          //             "acceptance": 0.6,
          //             "maxFeePerGas": 179.439035693,
          //             "maxPriorityFeePerGas": 38.61208831299999,
          //             "baseFee": 140.82694738,
          //             "estimatedFee": 0.027808056600612693
          //         },
          //         {
          //             "acceptance": 0.9,
          //             "maxFeePerGas": 194.160445601,
          //             "maxPriorityFeePerGas": 37.95632116599998,
          //             "baseFee": 156.204124435,
          //             "estimatedFee": 0.030089465427747035
          //         },
          //         {
          //             "acceptance": 1,
          //             "maxFeePerGas": 374.271472321,
          //             "maxPriorityFeePerGas": 206.47804750999998,
          //             "baseFee": 167.793424811,
          //             "estimatedFee": 0.058001661935497266
          //         }
          //     ]
          // }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error while getting transaction gas fee');
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
      return gas;
    }
```

Can somebody please let me know how to get transaction registered on blockchain Polygon?

Thanks a lot for your time in advance!